# Can you accidentally irreversibly disconnect a user with Cognito Identity Pools?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm just looking into using Amazon Cognito Identity Pools.

From my understanding, conceptually the federated ID becomes the user's one true ID in your application. So where ever you store user data, you are supposed to be relating it back to that federated ID. That's why, if you have say a Facebook and Twitter account associated with a particular identity, the user can use both to sign in and see their data in the application.

I read last night (and now for the life of me can't find where, but it was official documentation), that if you remove all logins for an identity in the identity pool, then that identity is then orphaned and unretrievable. Makes sense... there are no longer any logins associated with the actual human who owns it.

For illustration, this is how you set your logins in the Javascript SDK.

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
      Logins: {
        'graph.facebook.com': response.authResponse.accessToken,
        'other.provider':'other.provider.token',
        // etc
      }
    });
```

Where the `Logins` object could have many different providers set as well as Facebook (Google, Twitter, etc).

That's all fine and well, but what happens if some how, in one of the many different apps you might have using the identity pool, that a bug is introduced where the array of logins somehow manages to be empty and submitted through to the AWS Identity server.

Does that mean that this identity, which you would have used to build out the users entire experience with your app (such as their user profile, account data, potentially everything including sensitive data), would be irreversibly disconnected?

I hope I'm dreaming up an impossible worst case here. Can anyone alleviate my concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "Logins" map is deleted (not present) in the call to AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials() then all that will happen is that the credentials from the Identity Provider will fail to authenticate. Nothing will happen to your Identity Pool configuration in Cognito. Once the issue is corrected, all that the user will need to do is login again. Think of the Logins map as a hint to Cognito on which Identity Provider you are using, not a direction to change the Cognito configuration.

Comment: Thank John. So say after the map was deleted, the user logged in with Facebook. The authentication will fail of course. But then how would you then go about "reattaching" the facebook login to the correct IdentityId? As, the only way I currently understand to know which IdentityId it should be associated with, is if it is already currently associated with it? You would have to some where else have already created a duplicate association between the IdentityId and the Facebook login right? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Just correct the missing Logins map in your client source code (JavaScript) and re-login. The Logins map is required to authenticate using third party Identity Providers (IDP). The actual real IDP links are stored in Cognito Federated Identities with your third party IDP credentials. However, if you delete the IDP credentials in Cognito Federated Identities, then just add them back. Cognito uses the IDP JWT (token) to map identities. Note: I don't believe that Cognito deletes identities when you remove an IDP. I have never tested removing an IDP and then re-adding.

Comment: Note: when I say Logins map, I mean the parameter that you are passing to  AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials() and not the IDP stored within Cognito.

Comment: Oh ok, so basically you are saying that if your IdentityId ends up sitting in the identity pool without an empty log in map, later on when you create CognitoIdentityCredentials with your identity pool ID, and then add the IdP log in again, Cognito will automatically re-associate the IdP login to the IdentityId it was previously associated with. Does that sound right?

Comment: Cognito will re-associate the token every time a client user authenticates with Cognito. Within the token are the payload fields that Cognito (and your server side application) uses such as username or email address to identify who a particular user is and expiration to validate still authenticated. The token provides information on who the authenticated user is. The token expires often, so re-authentication / re-association normally happens numerous times for a single user identity.

Comment: John that's great information, thanks for clearing that up for me!

Comment: Chris, you are welcome. I have spent countless hours working with Cognito. I wish that I had someone to ask questions from when I first started working with Cognito.

Comment: Yeah it's certainly a lot to get your head around, especially when it's the architecture of your security mechanisms! Thanks again.

Comment: The next step after mastering Cognito authentication is to validate the JWT token which can be easily falsified if you don't verify the token signature. If you stick to JavaScript on the server (node.js) or Python then this will be easy. The other languages such as Java and PHP have a mess in the available libraries.

Comment: I'm alright with that actually, I've used Cognito User Pools before without identity provider, and really enjoyed using it. But now that I'm considering using an identity pool so that I can federate with Facebook, it's opened up a whole slew of confusion about where the centralised aspects of an account live, such as custom role permission for my back end API (i.e. "Paid User", "Free User"). Which used to live as custom attributes in my User Pool, but now will need to be stored else where in order to be associated with the Identity ID rather than directly on the user pool user.

Comment: IDPs such as Google and Facebook store their user identities in Windows local storage. This is how a login is remembered after you restart a browser session. For Cognito Federated Identities, now think of the Cognito User Pools as another IDP just like Facebook, etc. First you authenticate with the IDP and then pass the JWT token to Cognito Federated Identities to federate credentials. I wish Amazon would have chosen very different product names for the two (actually three) Cognito services AND would have released unique, clearly defined SDKs. It is a mess in my opinion today.